# How can I disable "selection by clicking " on GTK treeview

Tags: python, gui, gtk

I have this code where I get a treeview and a sign when I click or move the up / down over the lines. For my application I need to disable the selection when the user clicks on a row, further I wonder if there's any way to block the selection upwards. Thanks

```
treeview = builder.get_object('treeview3')
        treeview.set_model(liststore)
        select = treeview.get_selection()
        select.connect("changed", on_tree_selection_changed)

def on_tree_selection_changed(selection):
    model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
    if treeiter != None:
        print "You selected", model[treeiter][0]
```

Comment: Is this ubuntu?

Comment: Well, I'm working on ubuntu and when googled to find some method I found several similar answers here then .. I ask: D

Comment: That's fine :) We just have some (strange) rules about what is allowed here and what isn't!

Comment: This question does not belong to the allowed?

Comment: Nah, this is fine! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu - check out the [tour] if you have a spare minute or 2!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](//stackoverflow.com/q/30402782)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Gtk.TreeSelection.set_select_function`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSelection.html#Gtk.TreeSelection.set_select_function) functionality for this. Basically you give it a function, each time a row is selected this function is called. When it returns False the row can't be selected.

Here's an example:

```
treeview = builder.get_object("treeview3")
selection = treeview.get_selection()
selection.set_select_function(_select_func, None)

def _select_func(selection, model, path, selected, data):
    return False  # Can't select this row
```